# DataMapper associations/validation causing save failure

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

So I'm having some trouble with DataMapper and object associations. (Code provided at bottom). I'm getting errors upon saving to the extent that some id's are not set, which I think has something to do with how I setup my associations/not fully understanding how associations work under DataMapper.

The code I'm running is:

```
Rose.setup_datamapper
Rose::User.first_or_create(:username => 'some-user', :password => 'REDACTED')

Rose::User.all.each do |user|
   user.scrape_and_update
   user.errors.each { |e| puts e } unless user.save
   user.bandwidth_entries.each { |e| puts e }
end
```

And the errors I am recieving are:

```
 ~ (0.000064) SELECT "id", "username", "password" FROM "rose_users" WHERE ("username" = 'some-user' AND "password" = 'REDACTED') ORDER BY "id" LIMIT 1
 ~ (0.000042) SELECT "id", "username", "password" FROM "rose_users" ORDER BY "id"
 ~ rose_bandwidth_entries.device_network_address may not be NULL (code: 19, sql state: , query: INSERT INTO "rose_bandwidth_entries" ("policy_mbytes_received", "policy_mbytes_sent", "actual_mbytes_received", "actual_mbytes_sent", "timestamp", "bandwidth_class", "user_id") VALUES (583.34, 39.58, 590.27, 44.26,  '2011-09-20T13:39:31-04:00', 0.0, 1), uri: sqlite3:/Users/axiixc/Dropbox/Ruby/stats.sqlite?port=&adapter=sqlite3&fragment=&path=/Users/axiixc/Dropbox/Ruby/stats.sqlite&scheme=sqlite3&host=&user=&password=&query=)
```

Model classes are here: http://www.pastie.org/private/xer5grfaulmnxalne6g5va (link for brevity)

**EDIT** Okay the crash is coming from create on line 26:

```
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.1.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:114:in `execute_non_query': rose_bandwidth_entries.device_network_address may not be NULL (DataObjects::IntegrityError)

main_entry = BandwidthMainEntry.create(
    :user => self,
    :timestamp => Time.new,
    :policy_mbytes_received => scrape_dict[:main][:policy_mbytes_received],
    :policy_mbytes_sent => scrape_dict[:main][:policy_mbytes_sent],
    :actual_mbytes_received => scrape_dict[:main][:actual_mbytes_received],
    :actual_mbytes_sent => scrape_dict[:main][:actual_mbytes_sent],
    :bandwidth_class => scrape_dict[:main][:bandwidth_class]
 )
```

So would it have something to do with the inheritance from `BandwidthEntry/BandwidthDeviceEntry`, because that class doesn't even have an association with a device.

Might as well post the full stack trace too: http://www.pastie.org/private/ospnkeeylul9mhf4fgxhdq

**EDIT** Okay, here is basically the rest of the code http://www.pastie.org/private/pwmihpa6vu3h7lypx64ag

I can never tell how much to post, sorry!

Comment: Is there a stack trace for when that appears? Can you narrow down which line is triggering it?

Comment: You should probably try to reduce your problem to the one thing that fails and post all the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Notice that the trace sources in `scrape_and_update`, which we don't have the code for - can you post that method as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I derped on inheritance, and should have read more of the documentation. What was happening was I missed the `property :type, Discriminator` needed when using subclasses. So even though my one subclass didn't need a device associated with it, the other did, so that's what was triggering the error.

My working model looks like this: http://www.pastie.org/2564668

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, the value `device_dict[:network_address]` isn't getting set properly - that error indicates you're inserting a `NULL` device address, which comes from a `nil` value in your `create` call. Try checking the values in `device_dict` when you go to create device entries.

Comment: But that class shouldn't need a device_network_address, because it belongs to a user, not a device. So is it something with my inheritance that is messing it up?

Comment: Okay, I'm going to chock it up to the inheritance, because I took that out and made everything a distinct class, and now it all works well. So now I guess I get to go lookup how to do inheritance with DM right.